# Posting object with list of ints from jquery to .net mvc 3 controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having difficulty posting a JavaScript object via jQuery to a .net MVC 3 controller.

My object:

```js
var postData = {
    'thing1' : "whatever",
    'thing2' : "something else",
    'thing3' : [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

My jQuery Call:

```js
$.post('<%= Url.Action("Commit", "MassEdit") %>', postData, function (data) {
    // stuff
});
```

My View Model:

```cs
public class SubmitThing {
    public string thing1 { get; set; }
    public string thing2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> thing3 { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```cs
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Commit(SubmitThing changes)
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

The problem is that my 'changes' object that I have within my controller have thing1 equal to "whatever", thing2 equal to "something else", but thing3 is null.  Now do I get thing3 to be my list of integers?

**Added:** I think this is more of a mapping issue than a serialization issue.  In my controller, if I look at

```
HttpContext.Request.Form["thing3[]"]
```

I get a string with the value of "1,2,3,4".  But again, I'd like the mapping to just work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just post it as json:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("Commit", "MassEdit") %>',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({'thing1' : "whatever",
    'thing2' : "something else",
    'thing3' : [1, 2, 3, 4]
}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

and it should work

Comment: Is the MVC stuff designed to receive JSON in the request? Also, that post, as written, won't work. If you give it an object for `data`, jQuery *always* does URL-encoding on it, regardless of the `contentType` you specify. If you use a custom `contentType`, you have to serialize it yourself (e.g., `JSON.stringify` or similar) and specify `data` as a string. And you've given `dataType: 'json'` in your request, but that controls the type of what you're expecting *back*, not the type of what you're sending (despite the very confusing naming similarity with `data`).

Comment: yes you are right you have to stringify it, asp.net mvc 3 can receive json out of the box, the datatype json specifies the type you are expecting to get back from the server you can change it to whatever you will return, the contenttype specifies what you are sending to the server. I edited the post.

Comment: Good deal, that's cool if MVC 3 can receive it. I'd remove the `dataType` from the example to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why don't you join the values before passing them?

```
var thing3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

thing3 = thing3.join(',');

var postData = {
    'thing1' : "whatever",
    'thing2' : "something else",
    'thing3' : thing3 
}
```

otherwise i think you have to use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to have it serialaize the array

Comment: A bit of a hack, isn't it? Then he has to massage the data at the other end, rather than getting the nice mapping stuff the MVC gives him.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes it's an hack, i don't know anything about MVC3, but to have the array serialized you have to send the request with a parameter set and i don't think that parameter (traditional) is set when using the shortand $.POST

Comment: Yeah, this is my backup plan, but it would be nice if MVC did it for me. (which it should)

Comment: I don't have serialization problems getting it to the server.  If I look at **HttpContext.Request.Form["thing3[]"]** I get "1,2,3,4".  But again, I'd like the mapping to just work.

Comment: @Erik W Sorry i didn't understand that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in a web forms project, but I'm using `List<int>` instead of `IEnumberable<int>`  (edit to add:)  And it's working...  ;)

EDIT 2 :

Looking farther at what we're doing different.  Could you try building your object slightly differently and using `JSON.stringify()`?  The following is a bit closer to what's working for me...

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({
    thing1 : "whatever",
    thing2 : "something else",
    thing3 : [1, 2, 3, 4]
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work.  I tried IEnumerable, IList, an even int[] thing3, and nothing.

Comment: @T.J. List does implement IList? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx  Or am I missing something?  Regardless, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Erik: Sorry, I was thinking of `LinkedList`, not `List`.

Comment: @Erik:  Which didn't work?  the `List<int>` alone, or did you change your object as i suggested in the edit...  I see you accepted the other answer, which makes a similar change to the object, but I'm curious to know if you left it `IEnumerable<int>` or not...

Comment: @ShaneBlake: I left it at IEnumerable<int>.  The ultimate problem was that the jquery $.post was posting the individual properties like a form (so it was sending four "thing3[]"s), and the solution just posted a single json string, which .net mvc 3 apparently understood better.